# Copy image from raw folder to external sd card?

Tags: android

I use this code but it fails at the file outputstream.
When i make a static void then getResources will fail.

```
public void copy (Context context) {
InputStream in = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.high1);
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/pic1.jpg");
byte[] buff = new byte[1024];
int read = 0;

try {
   while ((read = in.read(buff)) > 0) {
      out.write(buff, 0, read);
   }
} finally {
     in.close();

     out.close();
}
```

}

Comment: **NEVER HARDCODE PATHS**. Use `getExternalFilesDir()`, or `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory()`, or something like that to get a directory on external storage to use.

Answer (score 0):

To getResources() do not fail when changing it to static, modify the line:

> InputStream in = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.high1);

To:

> InputStream in = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.high1);

Additionally, quoting CommonsWare:

> **NEVER HARDCODE PATHS.** Use getExternalFilesDir(), or Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(), or something like that to get a directory on external storage to use.